# SSAS Cube Process in Job fails

Tags: sql, ssas, jobs

I have some ssis packages & a cube to process in my job scheduled.
When I process the cube in visual studio, its working fine even I tried it manually in analysis services of sql, it works there too.
But my job fails saying the step of process cube.

Here is a part of the error message:

A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table: 'dbo_Customer', Column: 'Updated_By', Value: '

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done it at my own , One of my Excel templates have no value assigned in "updated by" column & so the database have no value in it. It coming as blank. so creating issue while processing cube.

Answer (score 1):

you should read about the UnknowMember on the dimension. It is common to come across situations where 
you have a Fact not related to a dimension.

Basically what it does is when facing this situation, instead of breaking the  refresh it will substitute the missing value by whatever you have configured on the UnknowMemberName (N/A for example)